# shiny: conflict between lubridate and shinyjs when using show method?

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate, shinyjs

I am working on an application where I use `shinyjs` package to hide and show the tabs of a `navbarPage` element. It works fine, until I decided to use the `lubridate` in my app for some other purpose. Just with the `library` call, the app freezes when I try to use the show/hide functionalities:

> Warning: Error in show: unused argument (selector = "#navbar li
>   a[data-value=mydata]")

My code (try it with or without the lubridate loading)

```
library(shiny); library(shinyjs); library(lubridate)
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), navbarPage(id="navbar", title="Analysis",
                                       tabPanel(title="Home", p("here is main page"), checkboxInput("show_other_tab", "show other tab?", value=FALSE)),
                                       tabPanel(title="My Data", value="mydata", p("some other text"))))
server = function(input, output, session){
     hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=mydata]")
     observe({
          if (input$show_other_tab) {
               show(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=mydata]")
          } else {
               hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=mydata]")}})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is my session.info(): R 3.4.2
[1] lubridate_1.7.1 shinyjs_0.9.1   shiny_1.0.5

What can be causing this and how to avoid this error? Thanks

Comment: note: the javascript lines are taken from Dean Attali here: https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint in line 9 (where the `show` is) and type `show` in your console, you will see that it is taken from package `methods`, not `shinyjs`:

```
Browse[2]> show
standardGeneric for "show" defined from package "methods"
```

Loading of lubridate seems to cause that. The cure would be to use `shinyjs::show` in that line, to make sure it is taken from `shinyjs` package.

And, by the way, since Shiny 1.0.4 there are built-in functions `showTab` and `hideTab` for that:

```
ui <- navbarPage(id="navbar", title="Analysis",
                 tabPanel(title="Home", id =p("here is main page"), checkboxInput("show_other_tab", "show other tab?", value=FALSE)),
                 tabPanel(title="My Data", value="mydata", p("some other text")))
server = function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    if (input$show_other_tab) {
      showTab("navbar", target = "mydata")
    } else {
      hideTab("navbar", target = "mydata")
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks, that really helps! Didn't know these new functions. This means that I no longer needs shinyjs package for this. I also noticed that if I load lubridate before shinyjs, I did =n't have any error

Comment: Thank you so much for this — I was really stuck.